# Why am I getting a stackoverflow error on index 0 in my array

Tags: java, stack-overflow

This is my warrior class. I wanted to have an array of warriors in this class.
The idea is to be able to call a method like this --> warrior.select(1) where it would get the warrior created at index 1. Hope that makes sense.
Please explain to me why this error is happening.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at pking.Warrior.<init>(Warrior.java:42)
```

Code

```java
package pking;

public class Warrior {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String call;
    private int attackPower;
    private String weapon;

    public Warrior(String myName, int myAge, String myCall, int myAttackPower) {
        name = myName;
        age = myAge;
        call = myCall;
        attackPower = myAttackPower;
        weapon = "";
        Warrior[] warriors = new Warrior[4];
        warriors[0] = new Warrior("Spartacus", 40, "I AM SPARTACUS!", 9000);
        warriors[1] = new Warrior("Crixus", 35, "CHAMPION OF CAPUA", 8000);
        warriors[2] = new Warrior("Gannicus", 30, "SLAYER", 8000);
        warriors[3] = new Warrior("Alexander", 21, "I AM ALEXANDER, THE CODER", 0);
    }

    //Prints warriors name
    public void name() {
        System.out.println(name);
    }

    //Prints warriors age
    public void age() {
        System.out.println(age);
    }

    //Prints warriors call
    public void warriorsCall() {
        System.out.println(call);
    }

    //Prints warriors attack power
    public void attackPower() {
        System.out.println(attackPower);
    }

    //Equips warriors weapon and prints message
    public void equip(String myWeapon) {
        weapon = myWeapon;
        System.out.println("Equiped the: " + weapon);
    }

    //Prints warriors weapon
    public void weapon() {
        System.out.println(weapon);
    }

}
```

Comment: You are invoking the `Warrior` constructor ***inside*** the `Warrior` constructor.  That is recursive.  Don't think that's what you were trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. So, you are saying that I can't create the warriors in the constructor. How should I go about doing this then? I tried creating the array right under the instance variables but I get the same error.

Answer (score 6):

Your constructor is running an infinite loop as you are calling it recursively.  Check these lines in your constructor :

```
    Warrior[] warriors = new Warrior[4];
    warriors[0] = new Warrior("Spartacus", 40, "I AM SPARTACUS!", 9000);
    warriors[1] = new Warrior("Crixus", 35, "CHAMPION OF CAPUA", 8000);
    warriors[2] = new Warrior("Gannicus", 30, "SLAYER OF VAGINAS", 8000);
    warriors[3] = new Warrior("Alexander", 21, "I AM ALEXANDER, THE CODER", 0);
```

for each Warrior array item instantiation you call the same constructor, which again try to create the array and initialise items, this keeps going on until stack overflows.

A better design strategy would be to create a new class, say `Legion`, which will contain a collection of `Warrior`s:

```
public class Legion {
    Warrior[] warriors;

    public Legion() {
        warriors = new Warrior[4];
        warriors[0] = new Warrior("Spartacus", 40, "I AM SPARTACUS!", 9000);
        warriors[1] = new Warrior("Crixus", 35, "CHAMPION OF CAPUA", 8000);
        warriors[2] = new Warrior("Gannicus", 30, "SLAYER OF VAGINAS", 8000);
        warriors[3] = new Warrior("Alexander", 21, "I AM ALEXANDER, THE CODER", 0);
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Hello Juned thanks for your answer. I am fairly new to programming and can't seem to wrap my head around this "recursion" error. I thought I was setting index 0 to a new warrior construct. Also the array is not in a while loop or anything so how could it recure? The only issue with this design that I just noticed is that everytime the program goes to the next index it sends new values to the instance variables and so forth. Perhaps you could dumb it down for me?

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to repeat the reason for the `StackOverflow` exception, as that has already been answered (recursion problem in your constructor).

But, I think that what you probably wanted was to create those 4 special warriors ***once*** and not for every instance of a `Warrior`.  And maybe you wanted to have them as constants somehow.

So maybe something like this:

```
public class Warrior {

    private static final List<Warrior> MEGA_WARRIORS =
        Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(
            new Warrior("Spartacus", 40, "I AM SPARTACUS!", 9000),
            new Warrior("Crixus", 35, "CHAMPION OF CAPUA", 8000),
            new Warrior("Gannicus", 30, "SLAYER OF *censored*", 8000),
            new Warrior("Alexander", 21, "I AM ALEXANDER, THE CODER", 0)
        ));

    public static List<Warrior> getMegaWarriors() {
        return MEGA_WARRIORS;
    }

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String call;
    private int attackPower;
    private String weapon;

    public Warrior(String myName, int myAge, String myCall, int myAttackPower) {
        name = myName;
        age = myAge;
        call = myCall;
        attackPower = myAttackPower;
        weapon = "";
    }

    //Prints warriors name
    public void name() {
        System.out.println(name);
    }

    //Prints warriors age
    public void age() {
        System.out.println(age);
    }

    //Prints warriors call
    public void warriorsCall() {
        System.out.println(call);
    }

    //Prints warriors attack power
    public void attackPower() {
        System.out.println(attackPower);
    }

    //Equips warriors weapon and prints message
    public void equip(String myWeapon) {
        weapon = myWeapon;
        System.out.println("Equiped the: " + weapon);
    }

    //Prints warriors weapon
    public void weapon() {
        System.out.println(weapon);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks you. I am fairly new to programming and can't seem to wrap my head around this "recursion" error. I thought I was setting index 0 to a new warrior construct. Also the array is not in a while loop or anything so how could it recure? The only issue with this design that I just noticed is that everytime the program goes to the next index it sends new values to the instance variables and so forth. Perhaps you could dumb it down for me?

Comment: Do you know what recursion is?  If not, google it.  Also, try running a program that has the main method coded like this: `public static void main(String[] args) { main(args); }`.  This is a very basic example of recursion which should help you see what is happening in your program.  And lastly, you also should figure out what was the purpose of your `warriors` variable?  Because, even if it was coded properly, once your constructor is finished, you don't save the `warriors` variable anywhere, so it doesn't seem to accomplish anything.